# Prism's ItemsControl seems to have a xaml parse error. Why?

Tags: silverlight, prism, itemscontrol

I am at a loss as to why my Shell.xaml's ItemsControl is causing a parse error. I know the syntax is correct because I copied the Silvelright project files from a working project.

Right now my only guess is that ItemsControl is dependent on something else.

Here is the relevant xaml line for ItemsControl.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Region" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                      Regions:RegionManager.RegionName="Region"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found that i wasn't Resolving my shell using unity. I had accidentally left it as VisualElement = new Shell.

Comment: Can you mark this as the answer so that it drops off the unanswered list, please.

Comment: A question is marked answered when at least one answer has at least one upvote.  You can't upvote your own answer, so I'm not sure what serialhobbyist was looking for from you in this case.